# Upload big files in SPA (angular + express)

Tags: angularjs, express, upload, single-page-application

Normal to upload file I do

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>      
    <p><input type='text', name='name'/></p>            
    <p><input type='file', name='image'/></p>      
    <p><input type='submit', value='Wyślij'/></p>    
</form>
```

What if I want send this form without page reload?

I can use "new FileReader()" and bind base64 to $scope but with big files it doesn't work well.

Can I upload my form without page reload in similar way like above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should looked at the directive which has been created already [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

**Features**

1. Supports upload progress, cancel/abort upload while in progress, File drag and drop (html5), Directory drag and drop (webkit), CORS, PUT(html5)/POST methods.
2. Cross browser file upload (HTML5 and non-HTML5) with Flash polyfill FileAPI. Allows client side validation/modification before uploading the file
3. Direct upload to db services CouchDB, imgur, etc... with file's content type using $upload.http(). This enables progress event for angular http POST/PUT requests.
4. Seperate shim file, FileAPI files are loaded on demand for non-HTML5 code meaning no extra load/code if you just need HTML5 support.
5. Lightweight using regular $http to upload (with shim for non-HTML5 browsers) so all angular $http features are available.

Comment: Tested their demo page with a ~200MB file, stalled at 0% no progress

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/ seems to handle large uploads very gracefully