# Uploading large video files using angular

Tags: angular

after googling for a way to upload a big file using angular 4, i found nothing.

i found this [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in this question [Upload big files in SPA (angular + express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332169/upload-big-files-in-spa-angular-express), but it's for angularjs, is there any thing for angular 4 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use ng2 file upload plugin for angular 4 [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload)

and you can upload large files also

Answer (score 1):

Sending a large file in one go may be hectic. there is implementation called upload/download files in chunks like torrent does. There is library named [Tus](https://tus.io/)

This library allow sending file in chunks and also resumable option is there. If any time user data over or any issue will come, user can resume file upload.